# Example to ilustrate reactive programming with RxJava

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming

Can you point to any coding example showing the power behind reactive programming with RxJava? (something which would be very slow/bad to solve without reactive) . I am not looking for examples showing the syntax but rather for a problem which is solved in RxJava elegantly and solved with other means would be ugly/cumbersome.

Comment: Your question is too broad. There are hundreds of blog posts demonstrating RxJava's various aspects and several books whose first chapters are dedicated to why RxJava.

Comment: Can you point to one very concrete example from the ones you know? i tried to point what I am looking for : I am not looking for examples showing the syntax but rather for a problem which is solved in RxJava elegantly and solved with other means would be ugly/cumbersome.

Comment: For instance this http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2017/08/loading-files-with-backpressure-rxjava.html. But here I cannot see the downsides of not using reactive (other than cool/elegant syntax). I'm looking for a problem which shows very bad performance WITHOUT reactive. Any links from the broad documentation and articles you know of? (I hope it is easier to reply to the point than to criticize!)

Comment: Why do you need this? Are you trying to convince somebody to use RxJava? Have you seen [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0IKHxjkgop4)?